# NumericTextBox value is not a number in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a strange problem with value in numericTextBox. I've got this error today:

ERROR Error: The NumericTextBox component requires value of type Number and {"value":null} was set.

In first sight, the problem is easy. But when I try to set a number value, problem still appears.

I try to get formControlName name from HTML in this way :

```
  <kendo-numerictextbox  [placeholder]="text" [spinners]="false"
    [format]="" formControlName="first" required></kendo-numerictextbox>


  takeIt= this.fobo.group({
    first: [{ value: 3 }, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(999999999)]]
```

fobo is injected in constructor from FormBuilder.
Where should I set a value? In HTML code or in ts code?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reference this link

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/slider/forms/

Note how the FormControl `slider` is instantiated

```
public form = new FormGroup({
           slider: new FormControl(5, SliderValidator(5))
       })
```

Your example is setting a default value in the `first` control of `{ value: 3}`, that is a json string.... try instantiating your control like below and the value should be of type `number`.

```
takeIt= this.fobo.group({
    first: [3, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(999999999)]]
```